# Hiding buttons/links on communication site in modern SP online

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, communication-site

I am working with HubSites in modern SP. On a communication site (registered as hub), I wanted to see if there is a way to hide the links that appears on the top right, see screenshot below.

[image]

I already have a modern script editor web part in use so if someone could share the CSS to hide these links that would be great. FYI, I am looking to hide Following/not following, share site and next steps links/buttons.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The following CSS style for your reference.

```
<style>
div[class^='sideActionsWrapper-']{
    display:none !important;
}
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: Just tested, but the snippet does not work, it does not hide the buttons/links.