# Hide "+ Create site" link on the hub site communication site home page

Tags: sharepoint-online

I create a new communication site and i define it as hub site, i am login as the site admin and as SharePoint online admin. where i got this "+ Create site" link:-

[image: thumbnail image 1 of blog post titled page]

is there a way to hide this "+ Create Site" link,for this site only? i know i can do this on the tenant level, as follow:-

[image]

but i need to do it for this site only.. is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Like you mentioned this can be done only at tenant level: [https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/11/sharepoint-online-how-to-hide-create-site-link.html#:~:text=To%20disable%20the%20%E2%80%9CCreate%20site%E2%80%9D%20link%2C%20follow%20these,on%20the%20%E2%80%9CSave%E2%80%9D%20button%20to%20save%20your%20changes%21](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/11/sharepoint-online-how-to-hide-create-site-link.html#:%7E:text=To%20disable%20the%20%E2%80%9CCreate%20site%E2%80%9D%20link%2C%20follow%20these,on%20the%20%E2%80%9CSave%E2%80%9D%20button%20to%20save%20your%20changes%21)

Hiding the "+ Create Site" link on a specific SharePoint communication site is not directly supported by SharePoint’s settings.

You may be able to achieve this by using CSS to hide the link, if you want to restrict site creation to certain users or groups, you might consider adjusting the permissions settings in SharePoint. This won’t hide the "+ Create Site" link, but it can prevent unauthorized users from creating new sites.

CSS Snippet [Hiding buttons/links on communication site in modern SP online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/267109/hiding-buttons-links-on-communication-site-in-modern-sp-online):

```
<style>
div [class^='sideActionsWrapper-'] {
  display:none !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Hiding SharePoint UI using custom CSS is unsupported for modern SharePoint pages: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-pages#supported-customizations-for-modern-pages